# Unsupported proxy in Ubuntu software center

Tags: software-center, 18.04, proxy

When i try to install apps from Ubuntu software center it's showing the error `Unsupported proxy configured`.
Proxy in terminal and browser is working fine.

[image]

Comment: Why does your proxy have a `//` before the port?

Answer (score 0):

In the network settings page, simply edit your settings as shown:

[image]

Good Luck!